# Disable new macos logging system

Tags: macos, high-sierra, logs

My SSD has bad blocks, so I get overwhelmed by those messages:

```
2018-07-07 21:24:03.950826+0000 0xd0       Default     0x0                  0      kernel: (IOStorageFamily) disk1s1: device error.
2018-07-07 21:24:03.950827+0000 0xd0       Default     0x0                  0      kernel: (IOStorageFamily) disk1s1: IO failed, error = 83.
```

They take too much of the log so `log` process begins to take more than 90% cpu.

Question: how do I block those messages in the new mac logging system or disable the system completely?

Tried to `sudo log config --mode "level: off"`, but when I do the `sudo log config` I see no change (when I use levels `default` or `info` the change works).

By the way, clearing the log with `log erase --all` makes the `log` process hush for a while, but I definitely ain't gonna put this in cron due to religious considerations.

Comment: Why not fix the issue by replacing the SSD?

Comment: @Allan bash commands are way cheaper, you know :D

Comment: Until you lose data...then it becomes priceless.

Comment: @Allan doesn't really make me anxious, since all data is always backed up somewhere, so my back is covered. Hence I'd delay the ssd replacement for as long as possible, but it's quite difficult with cpu eaten by the spammed log.

Comment: Why not mark the bad blocks as bad?  [Disk Drill](https://www.cleverfiles.com/) has this ability

Comment: @Allan that's a good idea, still it's important for me to take the log system down so my ego won't be crushed by that lil daemon

Comment: If you don't mind, could you please provide the response received to issuing this command: `sudo log config --status --subsystem com.apple.IOStorageFamily`? Thank you.

Comment: @DocG. Mode for 'com.apple.IOStorageFamily'  INFO PERSIST_DEFAULT

Comment: @DocG. should I specify the log level for this subsystem explicitly?

Comment: @DocG. Changed it to `Mode for 'com.apple.IOStorageFamily'  OFF PERSIST_OFF`, but still can see it in the `log stream`. Is it supposed to work like that?

Comment: It was *supposed* to work like you and I both hoped it would... It seems, however, that log messages at error- and fault-level are *always* streamed and saved to disk, and so, I think, is information logged by the kernel. Apparently this behavior cannot be altered from the default despite your success at obtaining `OFF PERSIST_OFF`. (P.S.: You'd be better served by using  Console.app or `log show` rather than `log stream` when possible; much less juggling of electrons in the CPU.) Sorry to be of no help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blend in the PID in the console.app (right click on the column description bar). Then disable logging like this:

`sudo log config --mode "level:off" --process *PID*`

Comment: Three years off, sadly, I don't have a chance to test it against my old bad SSD :(
I'll upvote and mark as the correct answer, for someone might make a good use of this